# misconceptions in market microstructure

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, high-frequency, market-microstructure

After an extensive research on the topic I felt that they are some ....errors,

I post on linkedin Myths in Market Microstructure Research I - passive liquidity providers-
and the the part II Myths in Market Microstructure Research II: discriminatory nature of the order book academia vs. industry
if someone wants to discuse more in depth these topics